# PHP: обратное преобразование массива в строку

Tags: php, mysql

Здравствуйте!

Подскажите, пожалуйста, можно ли в PHP преобразовать полученный из базы данных  массив в строку с PHP-кодом для создания массива?

Например, из базы данных я получаю:

```
 Array
    (
       [0] => Array
           (
               [mark] => Toyota
            )

       [1] => Array
           (
               [mark] => Nissan
            )

       [2] => Array
           (
               [mark] => Ваз
            )
```

Нужно преобразовать в :

```
$arr = array(
    array('mark' => 'Toyota'),
    array('mark' => 'Nissan'),
    array('mark' => 'Ваз'),
);
```

Нужно для того, чтобы лишний раз не отправлять запрос к базе. В ручную набивать массив очень долго.

Comment: Пока не очень понятно, вы хотите сформировать PHP-код?

Comment: @cheops Да,  хочу создать PHP код

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно начать отталкиваться от следующей рекурсивной функции

```
<?php
  $arr = array(
    array('mark' => 'Toyota'),
    array('mark' => 'Nissan'),
    array('mark' => 'Ваз'),
  );
  function build_array($arr) {
    $tmp = array();
    foreach($arr as $key => $child) {
      if(is_array($child)) {
        $tmp[] = build_array($child);
      } else {
        $tmp[] = "'$key' => '$child'";
      }
    }
    return  count($tmp) > 0 ? 'array('.implode(','.PHP_EOL, $tmp).')' : '';
  }
  $result = build_array($arr);
  echo '<pre>';
  print_r($result);
  echo '</pre>';
```

Результат работы скрипта

```
array(array('mark' => 'Toyota'),
array('mark' => 'Nissan'),
array('mark' => 'Ваз'))
```

Comment: кастыль же. ему просто надо незапрашивать лишний раз из mysql. а вы изобретаете велосипед serialize функции

Comment: @Naumov, в уточняющих комментариях автор сообщает об необходимости сформировать именно PHP-код. Сохранение сериализованного массива на диск далеко не факт, что будет быстрее базы данных, данные, а зачастую и результирующий запрос, в которой часто кэшированы в оперативной памяти. Я лишь ответил на вопрос автора не додумывая за него архитектуру приложения и кэш - вопрос не по ним.

Comment: а если вас спросят как мне стоку из utf8 в cp1251 а потом из cp1251 обратно в utf8 конвертировать. вы так же ответите прямолинейно.

Comment: @cheops Спасибо! Это то, что нужно!

Comment: @Naumov Зря вы так, cheops правильно понял задачу и самое главное потратил время на ее результативное решение.

Comment: @Naumov зависит от вопроса, здесь немного другой случай, в PHP действительно нет нормальной функции, которая бы выдавала дамп массива в готовом для использования в скриптах формате. Это часто неудобно, отвечая 12 лет на вопросы на различных форумах я провел часы формируя из дампов массивы, на которых бы можно было продемонстрировать решение. Поэтому мне эта задача показалась интересной, в первую очередь для себя. У вас другой ответ - вы его опубликовали. Завтра у меня снова появятся плюсы, я его плюсану. А те кто придет за ответом в тему позже - выберут подходящий им вариант.

Comment: для датапровайдера в юнит тестах да круто. но не для скрипта который где то работает. По этому я считаю, это мое мнение. стоило бы у человека кзнать о целесообразности такого подхода.

Comment: @Naumov, особенность SO в том, что тут особо не задискутируешь... плохо оформленный вопрос отправляется в топку, те вопросы, которые интересны посетителям получают ответы. Этот вопрос получил 4 ответа - значит, он хороший, значит привлечет посетителей, а они уже голосами расставят, как им видится правильнее. Допускаю, что мой ответ наберет меньше голосов, чем остальные три. Расспрашивать автора об системе, которую он отлично знает, а я в глаза не видел - не тот формат ресурса, не удобно. Лучше пусть задает еще вопросы, а задавать он их будет только если будет получать ответы на предыдущие.

Answer (score 2):

Есть нативный [var_export](http://php.net/manual/en/function.var-export.php)

```
$arr = array(
    array('mark' => 'Toyota'),
    array('mark' => 'Nissan'),
    array('mark' => 'Ваз'),
);
var_export($arr); // вывести сразу
echo var_export($arr, true); // или вернуть строку
```

Answer (score 1):

Как вариант:

```
    $r = [
    ['mark' => 'Toyota'],
    ['mark' => 'Nissan'],
    ['mark' => 'Ваз'],
];


$write_in_file = file_put_contents("cars.json", json_encode($r));

$read_from_file = json_decode(file_get_contents('cars.json'), 1);
echo '<pre>';
var_dump($read_from_file);
die('</pre>');
```

Answer (score 1):

используйте `serialize` для сериализации масива в строку и записи куда то в фаил  для кэширование для преобразование опять в массив `unserialize`